# Requirements to keep vassal when they inherit foreign lands

Tags: crusader-kings-2

What are the requirements for keeping someone as your vassal when they inherit/conquer lands outside your realm ?

The wiki says they most already hold an equal title in your realm, but I've had many counts inherit foreign duchies. But when a baron inherited a foreign duchy, he left my realm and took his barony with him. I then assumed the rule was they can only inherit a title one rank up from the one they currently have, but a duke inheriting a kingdom leaves your empire.

So from what I can tell, the rules are somewhat arbitrary. What are the requirements for keeping a vassal when they inherit a holding/county/duchy/kingdom?

Comment: Were your crown authority laws the same in both instances? What was your character's rank in each instance? If you were a king or emperor in the first instance, but a duke yourself in the second, that could explain this behavior.

Comment: I was an emperor with high crown authority for all described situations. The only thing that really changed was which foreign realm my vassals were inheriting from. How is it supposed to work? The wiki says a count inheriting a duchy should leave your realm, but that has never happened for me with any crown authority (I've never set crown authority to min/low though and I've always been at least a king).

Comment: Could I have a link to where in the wiki you're looking?

Comment: http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Expanding_your_realm#Arranging_for_vassals_to_inherit_foreign_territory

Relevant text: "If a vassal inherits an equal or lower title outside your realm, your realm will grow correspondingly larger." and "If your vassal inherits a higher title than they hold, your realm will shrink instead!"

Comment: Looking at that, I think its just that that article on the wiki is poorly worded and vague. Let me write up an answer that I think is relevant to what you're experiencing.

Comment: If a vassal count inherits a foreign duchy, he will no longer be your vassal because Duchy>County, and he will take the county with him if your laws allow it. Anyone who inherits higher will do this. In theory a count could inherit a kingdom.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I'm actually not sure why this is happening... Under high crown authority any character whose inheritance would cause you to lose land to a foreign realm should be disqualified from succession. Do you happen to know the crown authorities of the realm you took land from/ took land from you in these situations?

Comment: I believe high crown authority affects how titles in your kingdom are inherited (it disqualifies those landed in foreign realms from succession), not how your vassals inherit foreign titles and become a vassal of that title's liege. I can believe that the rule is inheriting a duchy needs a county and inheriting a kingdom needs a kingdom (and I believe inheriting a county merely requires them to have a holding in your realm, but I haven't checked that), it just disagrees with the wiki is all (and convention).

Comment: In every case where a person already owns land as your vassal, any title that he inherits that is of lower rank than your title results in him remaining your vassal. That's it. There are no exceptions to this excepting bugs. Can you provide more information or a save? What did he inherit/own before?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what will be their primary title after inheritance. If a title being inherited is a higher tier title then this will always end up being their primary title. If this title is outside your realm then the inheriting vassal will leave your realm. If the title is equal or lower rank as what they currently hold then their current title will be their primary title and they will stay in your realm. If the realm of the inherited title has high crown authority then your noble will be unable to inherit the lands (and thus the land will stay in your realm, paradoxically).

As far as I understand, your realm having high crown authority only prevents foreign nobles from inheriting titles from your realm and taking them to another realm, but it does not prevent *your* nobles from inheriting foreign titles and leaving your realm.

Comment: I've had counts in my empire inherit duchies from a foreign empire and remain my vassal, that's the confusing part.

Comment: When they inherited a duchy was that an independent duchy or a part of another realm?

Comment: Part of another empire.

Comment: That doesn't square with what I've read, but if what you are saying is the actual and intended behaviour then it does indeed sound arbitrary. Would you have a screenshot of this?